# Override phtml if the module doesnt have in design theme folder?

Tags: magento2

How to override the phtml files using custom theme method if the phtml files are not present in the core design theme folder?

Eg: `CatalogSearch` module, how to override `result.phtml` file?

`app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_CatalogSearch\` has only web folder... no templates folder.

Should i copy `result.phtml` from modules `code/../view` folder to my custom theme in `app/design`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to just copy inside your theme folder,

**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/themenae/Magento_Catalogsearch/templates/restul.phtml`**

Comment: i know the destination to be copied..what i asked was, if the result.phtml is not there in app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/result.phtml then should i copy from another location ie) from code folder??

Comment: yes definately you have to copy from magento2.1/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml file

Comment: I dont have /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search instead app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/... hope both are same!

Comment: yes you can copy from there

Answer (score 0):

**It could help someone**

The correct path is the same as @Rakesh Jesadiya but With `Magento_CatalogSearch`, `Magento_Catalogsearch` doesn't work so :

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/resutl.phtml
```